# Async pymodbus application doesn't work after reading from "IllegalAddress"

Tags: python, asynchronous, tcp, modbus

**Application**: Python 2.7 + Pymodbus 1.4.0 (asynchronous client)

**Problem**: I want to handle a situation when user wants to read from the wrong address (Illegal Address) in asynchronous version, but my solution does not work.

**Simplified code - asynchronous version:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
from pymodbus.client.async import ModbusClientProtocol
from twisted.internet import serialport, reactor


def print_result(response, address):
    try:
        print("Response: ", response.registers[0])
    except:
        print("Response: ", response)


def start_measurements(client):
    # 16408, 16409 addresses are ok
    # 9015 is an Illegal Address
    addresses = [16408, 9015, 16409]

    for address in addresses:
        rr = client.read_holding_registers(address, 1, unit=255)
        # setting Callback/Errback function with an address argument
        rr.addBoth(print_result, address)

    reactor.callLater(10, client.transport.loseConnection)
    reactor.callLater(11, reactor.stop)


def handler_tcp_connection_error(client):
    print("Error while connecting")
    reactor.callLater(0, reactor.stop)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    defer = protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, ModbusClientProtocol).connectTCP("192.168.168.100", 502)
    defer.addCallbacks(start_measurements, handler_tcp_connection_error)

    reactor.run()
```

When I read from these registers in synchronous version I just don't receive a value from wrong address, but further registers are read anyway.

In asynchronous version (pasted above) when Illegal Address is read, I've got no response even from further registers and the **output** is:

```
Response: 15
Response:  Exception Response(131, 3, IllegalAddress)
*waiting about 10s with no response*
Response:  [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'pymodbus.exceptions.ConnectionException'>: Modbus Error: [Connection] Connection lost during request]
```

I'd like to get all correct values (not from Illegal Addresses) like in the synchronous version:

```
Response: 15
Exception Response(131, 3, IllegalAddress)
Response 7
```

**How can I fix this, to skip IllegalAddreses and get values from all correct addreses?**

Comment: What device are you using? Some address readings can only be read if the buffer is linked to memory. Comments are not clear? Read the technical documentation of the device.

Comment: Eliwell avd12600, but I'd like to have a device independent solution. Just to skip illegal addreses and read from the others. And I'm also confused because synchronous version works without any problem.

Comment: They did it so I wouldn't be connected to your device. To ensure the safety of the appliance, it is ensured to receive packets continuously. If the delay is longer than a certain time (example: profinet < 200ms) The external access is detected and the query is rejected.

Comment: Another reason: The data assignments of your device are not readable if they are not assigned to the buffer. This access list is required for storing and preparing the data. Interesting status ! SCADA applications can't delay more than 60ms(so why using RTU ?)